# Hats missing on chat user profile

Tags: feature-request, chat, winter-bash, winter-bash-2014

In short:

[image]

Seems this year hats are everywhere else, including chat rooms, but just not on actual chat profiles. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Refresh the page - after a F5, is it there?

Comment: @Oded No... :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

balpha was going to add the hats there, but he oversized the one he was wearing and it covered his eyes, making getting it in that change at the last minute impossible. We'll have to save our dreams of truly universal hats* for the future.

<sub>*There are no hats on the network profile either</sub>